# Column data types not being maintained using pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a function that takes in a pandas DF and saves it to my DB (SQL Server):

```
def save_to_stg(df, engine, table_name):
    df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False,
              dtype={
                    'foo': sqlalchemy.Boolean(),
                    'bar': sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(255),
                    'baz': sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(16),
                    'date': sqlalchemy.Date()
                  })
```

After running this function, I can see the data types correctly specified in my staging table in SQL Server using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

```
COLUMN_NAME           DATA_TYPE          CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
foo                      bit                         NULL
bar                    varchar                       255
baz                    varchar                       16
date                     date                        NULL
```

Now I want to query this table and and save it to another table like this:

```
def stg_to_final(staging_table, engine, final_table):
     sql = f"""
        SELECT * FROM {staging_table}
     """
    
    df_final = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)

    df_final.to_sql(final_table, con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

But the datatypes in my final table did not get maintained correct. All the `varchar` got reset to varchar(max) type while the boolean (bit) and date datatypes are preserved.

```
COLUMN_NAME           DATA_TYPE          CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
foo                      bit                         NULL
bar                    varchar                       -1
baz                    varchar                       -1
date                     date                        NULL
```

How can I preserve these varchar datatypes? I need all the column datatypes from the staging table to be maintained. In reality, there are a lot more columns and I don't want to have to specify all the dtype again in my second function.

Please advise.

Comment: Why not just save the dictionary of `dtype` values to a variable and use it in both `to_sql()` calls?

Comment: @GordThompson the dtype variable will actually be different in my second function because I need to add a few more columns there.

Comment: When you use [`to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) with `if_exists='replace'` you're telling it to drop the target table and then recreate it using the data types inferred from the DataFrame. If you want to keep the existing table's structure and data types have you considered either truncating or deleting its contents first and then use `if_exists='append'` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the data types in `to_sql`, they are mapped from the data types of the Pandas dataframe, which are just ordinary Python types.  And Python doesn't have a `varchar(16)` type.